# nothing is displayed with the use of prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

how do I improve on the codes below so that my page actually works?

```
function getCategoryConn($conn, $cat, $status) {
$result = array();
if(!$conn->connect_error) {
    $sqlstr = "SELECT cat, item, price, img, description " .
            "FROM product P, category C " . 
            "WHERE P.cat=C.cat AND P.cat=? AND C.cat=? ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlstr);
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $cat, $status);   //line 37
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($cat, $item, $price, $img, $description);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result[$cat] = ["cat" => $cat,
                         "item" => $item,
                         "price" => $price,
                         "img" => $img,
                         "description" => $description];
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
return $result;
}
```

I have 4 different types of data in $cat. How do I define it such that all the 4 types of data can be displayed?

```
$productArr = getCategoryConn($conn, $cat, STATUS_ACTIVE);   //line 39 - the question I'm asking above

foreach ($productArr as $cat => $products) {
    if ($_GET['cat'] == $cat) {
        foreach ($products as $item => $info) {
               //foreach loop here
        } 
    }
}
```

I currently have these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: cat in XXXXXXXXXXXX on line 39

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in XXXXXXXXXXXX on line 37
```

Comment: `bind_param("i"` you're only using a single parameter against four.

Comment: `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` will show you errors if any.

Comment: *"Do the WHERE clause above actually works?"* - Have you tried it?

Comment: yes. i've tried a few different ways too. all the results were the same @Fred-ii-

Comment: look at my answer below syh, it goes into further detail than how @Fred-ii- explained it.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have 4 `?`

```
$sqlstr = "SELECT cat, item, price, img, description " .
        "FROM product P, category C " . 
        "WHERE P.cat=? = C.cat=? AND " .
        "P.status=? = C.cat=? ";
```

for each `?` you need to tell `bind_param()` what kind of variable `?` is.

So for example, if you have the following:

```
$this_is_int = 5;
$this_is_string = 'test';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and username = ?';

/*
    Binds variables to prepared statement

    i    corresponding variable has type integer
    d    corresponding variable has type double
    s    corresponding variable has type string
    b    corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
*/

// Since we have two `?` in our query, we must defined two inputs in our bind_params()

// Order of ? in the query matters!

// So in the above example, this is how bind_param(), would be set.

$stmt->bind_param('is', $this_is_int, $this_is_string)
//                 ^  relates to  ^ and ^
//           First one is `i` for int, and second one is `s` for string
//
// which relates to SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and username = ?
//            The following order relates to above ^ ----- and ---- ^
```

So you have this

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $cat, $status);
```

1. Two things are wrong here, you only have 1 type setter `i` in the first parameter, but you have 4 question marks in the query.
2. You only have `$cat` and `$status`, when you have 4 question marks in the query.

So if `$status` was a string, this is how it should be written correctly:

```
$stmt->bind_param("iisi", $cat, $cat, $status, $cat);
```

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation! now i'll revise the question above. please help me out if possible @Arian Faurtosh

Comment: @syh dont revise it, if your question is different, write a new, clear, thought out question